# Can I delete data under Application Support directory in iOS App programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems

I am working in an App that displays new images and informations from server. There has been complaint from users as the size of iPhone Storage has grown over 2 GB in some cases.

I deleted the cache, even cleared the cache of Kingfisher library (used in app for image caching) but it didn't help. I then downloaded the Documents and Data content of the App from Xcode, as suggested in this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37366694/1917958). It was clear that the heavy chunk of data was under ".(appName)_SUPPORT" > "_EXTERNAL_DATA" folder in Application Support directory. I removed it programatically. I was able to decrease the size of app from whopping 850 MB to 195 MB in my device storage.

My concern is about safety of removing the items in this folder while user opens the app each time. I have also read Apple's documentation about [File System](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1), but it is still not clear that if it would be safe to remove this folder.

I would appreciate if anyone has more knowledge regarding this practice.

Comment: Personally I would not just delete the whole contents of the folder. It's quite likely that the folder taking up space within the Application Support folder was the Cache folder. You should be able to clear that at any time without issues as the system can also clear it at any time